# What are bastards named in Essos?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We know that bastards born in Westeros are named Snow, Pyke, Sand, Waters etc.

**But what is a bastard born in Essos named?**

Comment: I don't think we've ever met a bastard outside of Westeros. Besides, the social system is completely different and  bastards might be treated differently. And Essos is *huge*.

Comment: @SystemDown Huge, but sparsely populated from [what we can tell](http://i.imgur.com/CVAT5nc.jpg).

Comment: @RoyalFlush - Perhaps, but it also has a bazillion cultures and nations.

Comment: @SystemDown - Right, so even if we did meet any Essos bastards, how they are treated would likely vary depending upon which culture they were born into over there...

Comment: @Justin: On numerous occasions, Second Sons' Daario Naharis mentioned that his mother was a whore; and the former head of the Second Sons was called "The Titan's Bastard". So we did meet a few Essosian bastards.

Comment: @Jubobs: True. And at the same breath one might say that we don't know if The Titan's Bastard is truly a bastard, or if this is just a nickname to instill fear. Still, my guess is that both are *probably* bastards.

Comment: Hizdahr zo Loraq (http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hizdahr_zo_Loraq) has natural born children. I don't know if they are given a name or not yet...

Comment: Note: "bastards born in Westeros" is inaccurate. What you actually mean is "bastards of recognized high-born nobles in nine distinct subregions of Westeros" ( http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bastardy#Surnames ).

Comment: @FooBar is correct only noble born and known bastards get those surnames e.g. Edric Storm and Gendry. Both have the same father but one has the noble Surname the other doesn't because Gendry is not acknowledged. Interesting thing, their sister Mya is called Mya Stone even though Robert never officially recognized her but whole vale knows who the father is thus she also gets the surname stone.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike Westeros, [Essos is a heterogeneous continent](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Essos#People) of ethnicities, languages, and cultures. As such, it does not have a unified standard for treatment of extramarital children (or anyone else).

Answer (score 7):

The bastard names you're referring to are in replacement for family names, so children outside marriage don't bring shame on the family.

In both the book and the series it's suggested that only parts of Westeros, not essos use family names. (The wildings are natives of Westeros and don't use Family names)

In Essos most folks don't even seem to know Jorah Mormont has a family name and call him Jorah the Andal.

Note the conversation between Shae and Varys

> Varys: If you let yourself believe that a foreign girl with no name could spend her life with the son of Tywin Lannister...
>
> Shae: I have a name.
>
> Varys: You have one name. As do I. Here only the family name matters.

Update: In direct answer to the question, What is a bastard in Essos called? By his or her given name without indication of birth in or out of wedlock.

Answer (score 2):

**It is unknown for certain; but it seems that it is nothing special.**

As Geroge R. R. Martin says, in essence: [**Only high-born children get a "bastard" name**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22205/21267).
I'll quote from my answer there:

> Bastard names are given only to bastards with at least **one parent of high birth**. So the bastard child of two peasants would have no surname at all.
>   Thus a bastard name like "Snow" or "Rivers" is simultaneously a stigma and a mark of distinction. **The whole thing with bastard names is custom, not law**.
> <sup>*-http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/2999.*</sup>

So you can see that it is *customary* for natural children to receive the "[bastard](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bastardy)" name; and given that it is a custom of [Westeros](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Westeros), **it stands to reason that only "Westerosi" bastards receive the regional surnames.**

The only notable mention of a non-Westerosi having natural children is **[Hizdahr Zo Loraq](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hizdahr_zo_Loraq)** - who has fathered two natural children. But we do not know what their last names are.

> Though I have never wed, I have two natural children, a boy and a girl, .... 
> <sup>[Hizdahr from *A Dance With Dragons*]</sup>

Comment: +1. Also, to emphasize your point on only highborn bastards getting such surnames, you can use what Stannis said to Davos. **I know his name. Was there ever a name so apt? It proclaims his bastardy, his high birth, and the turmoil he brings with him. Edric Storm. There, I have said it. Are you satisfied, my lord Hand?**

Answer (score 0):

Bastards of Essos must have had two names. I'm basing this on Shiera Seastar who was a bastard of a Targaryan and a mother of Lys (which happens to be in Essos). Her mother was Serenei of Lys. Seastar must be the bastard name given to those from Lys.

Comment: That is wrong. Shiera is a lyseni name which is translated in common tongue as Seastar. She is called Seastar as a nickname or a title just like her half brothers were called Blackfyre, Bittersteel and Bloodraven